# What is the meaning of 金〇

Tags: manga, symbols

I wanted to ask what the '◯' symbol underneath the 金 means below? It seems the black-haired guy is asking the other guy something that's to do with drinking?

[image]

Answer (score 27):

This 金〇 is [金麦](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%91%E9%BA%A6), a well-known beer brand by Suntory Ltd. You can see the character 麦 on the can.

Here 麦 is masked by the circle [in order to avoid issues regarding trademarks or conflict of interest](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30663/5010). This is a common tradition in Japanese anime/manga industry. In Japanese, a circle is commonly used to sensor a part of a word for various reasons. See also: [Why censor this one kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11810/5010)